# Datatable button event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

This is my code which I am using for my DataTable :

```
  var oTable12= $('#example').DataTable({
       "aaData": tableData,
       "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
       "iDisplayLength": 5,
       "aoColumnDefs" :tableColumn
       });
```

I am adding column headers and default content in tableColumn array and then using it in aoColumnDefs .

I am getting perfect UI as it is expected, but when I click the button I get the following error :

***Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined***

This is my code for button click :

```
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
      var data = oTable12.row(0).data();
      alert( data);
    } );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change  your `table` to `oTable12`

```
  var data = table.row(0).data();
```

to

```
  var data = oTable12.row(0).data();
```

see if this works for you  :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: table is not defined

This is what I am getting after making changes as follows :

var data = oTable12.row(0).data();

Comment: can you update the question with all the changes you did

Comment: how can you get table as undefined when it doesnt not even exists in your code

Comment: i recommend rechecking for the changes where are you making your changes

Comment: I don't know actually I am learning Datatables so while following the examples I encountered this error

Comment: if you learning are you making changes in right place, are you reloading your page properly and other things that should be kept in mind

Comment: This is the html I am using for my table I am not sure whether I am correct or not :

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" aria-describedby="bTable2_info" style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
  
  </tbody>
  
   </table>

Comment: I have also tried other solution like changing DataTable to dataTable and vice versa but it still did not worked.

Comment: If I simply alert with random text on button click it is working fine , Only when I add the row function then I encounter the error

Comment: Is there any way by which I can check which version of datatable I am using

Answer (score 0):

Because table is not defined in your current context.Replacing table with **oTable12** will do trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved :

This was due to version problem, now I downloaded the latest version and now it is working correctly

Thank you to all of you for your precious reply and support